# Vigenère cipher decryption

Tags: bash, encryption, scripting, vigenere

I'm trying to make encryption and decryption with a Vigenère cipher.

It's a part of a greater task where the Vigenère cipher plays a small part. I got this encryption script from bash to work. The problem is how i get to use the same code in reverse to decrypt the code.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
# vigenere.sh
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher

a="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

[[ "${*/-d/}" != "" ]] &&
echo "Usage: $0 [-d]" && exit 1
m=${1:+-}

printf "string: ";read t
printf "keyphrase: ";read -s k
printf "\n"
for ((i=0;i<${#t};i++)); do
  p1=${a%%${t:$i:1}*}
  p2=${a%%${k:$((i%${#k})):1}*}
  d="${d}${a:$(((${#p1}${m:-+}${#p2})%${#a})):1}"
done
echo "$d"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what it does just launch it with bash `-x` option set, for example if script is saved in `vig.sh`:

```
bash -x vig.sh
```

basically, `a` to store the uppercase alphabet

`-d`, is an optional parameter to decrypt when set `m` will bet set to `-`

this reads from input `t` to store the source string, `k` the key

```
printf "string: ";read t
printf "keyphrase: ";read -s k
```

the following makes a loop over character indices of variable `t`

```
for ((i=0;i<${#t};i++)); do
```

`p1` contains the alphabet with the suffix begining with current character from `t` removed

```
p1=${a%%${t:$i:1}*}
```

`p2` does the same with current character from key (with a modulo to avoid out of bounds)

then the sum or difference (when -d option is set) between `p1` and `p2` lengths is used to get the character in alphabet and appended to `d`.

Examples

```
vig.sh
string: HELLOWORLD
keyphrase: FOO
-> MSZQCKTFZI

vig.sh -d
string: MSZQCKTFZI
keyphrase: FOO
-> HELLOWORLD
```

Comment: Thank for your answer - Im totally blank still, eventhough i understand some of your explanations. but on how to reverse so i can use it to decrypt i have no clue where to start

Comment: I have been trying 2 hours now to see if i could decrypt by the explanation u have givin.. I see your examples, but dont unerstand pr say. 

Do i still need A=ABCDE... in the decryption script first of all thats ? In my mind a="$d" in the decryption, but where do i get the alphabit  declared

Comment: + a=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
+ [[ '' != '' ]]
+ m=
+ t=TEST
+ printf 'Plaintext: '
Plaintext: + read -s k
+ printf '\n'

+ (( i=0 ))
+ (( i<4 ))
+ p1=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
+ p2=
+ d=T
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<4 ))
+ p1=ABCD
+ p2=A
+ d=TF
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<4 ))
+ p1=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
+ p2=AB
+ d=TFU
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<4 ))
+ p1=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
+ p2=ABC
+ d=TFUW
+ (( i++ ))
+ (( i<4 ))
+ echo TFUW
TFUW
+ echo TFUW
+ gzip
running my script with -x i see that it takes the length of the text and does something with each letter, which i dont understand how to use

Comment: a=ABCDEF..Z, is just a trick to go from a number to a letter and go back, for example for the letter `I`: `p=${a%I*}; echo ${#p}`will give `8` and starting from `8` : `echo ${a:8:1}` will give `I`

Answer (score 0):

to run the decryption, type ./vig.sh -d in the commmand. That should do it since you have declare the [[ "${*/-d/}" != "" ]] in the code.